# Npm package vulnerability shown on unknown dependency

Tags: npm

```
  Low             Regular Expression Denial of Service

  Package         braces

  Patched in      >=2.3.1

  Dependency of   a58756aede32d840bef41a981869afe3c3e5496efa127beade08d0034…

  Path            a58756aede32d840bef41a981869afe3c3e5496efa127beade08d0034…
                  > cpx > chokidar > anymatch > micromatch > braces

  More info       https://npmjs.com/advisories/786
```

I'm not sure what `Dependency of a58756aede32d840bef41a981869afe3c3e5496efa127beade08d0034` is referring to. Normally it shows an actual package I have in the package.json file. Also I have no dependency on `braces` in the package.json file either.

The only reference to `braces` I could find was in package-lock.json

Comment: how about try search for 'braces' in package-lock.json?

Comment: I did and found a reference. It probably is a peer dependency on one of the pacakges I have in the package.json file. package.json doesn't have any direct ref to `braces`.